What is the size (weight, capacity) of a battery able to absorb 10 kW while charging?
Due to some existent surplus of power generated by an electric generator, I need to find a battery able to absorb about 10 kW while in charging mode. The capacity of this battery does not really have to be greater than 20 kWh but unfortunately it has to absorb 10 kW for periods of time of the order of 15 minutes followed by intervals of time of 30 - 45 minutes when little or no surplus power exist.
Question: Can a 20 kWh battery absorb 10 kW while in charging mode but without shortening its lifetime? If this is not possible then what battery should I use? One of 100 kWh?

Is the battery able to discharge during the 30-45 minutes that it is not charging? If not, what prevents the battery from reaching its maximum state of charge?

More important is what prevents it from being overcharged?

The generator usually works 8 hours a day. The battery can be discharged in the remaining 16 hours. If the battery is fully charged and nobody uses its power then the surplus of power of the generator will be dissipated on a resistor, for example.

What's the reason you can't stop the generator when there is no demand? Skip the battery all together.

@MOSFET, The generator works continually at least 8 hours a day. The battery is aimed at storing only the surplus of power.

@RobertWerner  ***The generator works continually at least 8 hours a day. *** Is that because the load demand is there, or because its on timer and is obligated to run for on a set schedule regardless of demand?  Is there no other source of power, like the AC grid, or an inverter with a battery?

A 20 kWh lithium ion or lithium iron phosphate battery could certainly charge at 10 kW.  It's only a charge rate of 0.5C.  Many electric cars charge faster than that.
If you had a 100 kWh battery, then 10 kW would be trickle charging.
Any lithium battery needs a properly designed battery management system.  If the battery is run flat, it can be permanently damaged.  If it is over-charged, it can catch fire.
The maximum charge rate depends on the state of charge.  If it's nearly flat or nearly full, then the charge rate should be kept low.
Provided you keep the charge level between about 20% and 80%, it can be charged and discharged however you like.  At any speed up to the manufacturer's specified limit, and switching between charging and discharging in an instant.

Your answer is encouraging. I guess that lithium ion or lithium iron phosphate batteries of any capacity can charge at 0.5 C. So, assuming I have a 40 kWh battery, there will be no problem if I charge it at up to 20 kW. Another issue would be that the surplus power is not constant for 15 minutes. It can decrease or increase with  say 2-3 kW/min. Here, I do not know whether charging under inconstant power shortens the lifetime of a battery.

A small hydropower storage unit may have better useful life than any battery, especially if you can put the reservoir high above the pump/generator.
Let’s say it’s about 13W to pump at 1L/s rate up 1m height difference, including losses. You’d be pumping 1000L/s divided by the height. Say you can pump to 25m above the inlet. That’s 40L/s flow rate, or 2400L/min. You need a tank that can hold about 500,000L for 20min of pumping. That’s roughly a 9m diameter spherical tank. You’ll need two of them - one at the bottom, one at the top. Head pressure would be 2.5bar, so nothing outrageous.
After initial fill it should be a closed system. Properly designed with corrosion inhibitors in the water and sacrificial electrodes, the tanks will outlast everyone alive today. The pump/gen can be oversized 2.5x to make it last forever as well.
Hopefully you’re in a place warm enough where that water won’t freeze. Dealing with 500kL of glycol mix would be a bit of a pain due to the need for secondary containment.
